# How can I compare two strings from different tables in same SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I tought it would be something like this:

```
Cursor c = contactDBHelper.listOne(id);
    Cursor d = contactDBHelper.listOneText();

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            if(c.getString(5).toString() == d.getString(1).toString()){
                txt.setText(d.getString(1));

            }else{
                customR.setChecked(true);
                txt.setText(c.getString(5));    
                standardR.setChecked(false);
            }


        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
```

But apperently its not. Anyone got any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Always use `equals` method instead of `==`. It will give you more precise answer than `==`.

Comment: Sorry. thats what I had first. Didnt work

Comment: Sorry. Had that at first. Didnt work. Please unmark this question so i can edit it. The solution linked as duplicated does not work in my case

Comment: try to print both `strings` if they don't match.

Comment: If the `String`s are not `equal`s then there's a problem with your `String`s. Try to print them out and wrap them between `"` to check if there are no blank spaces.

Comment: After some debugging I found out the problem is I cant reach d.getString(), am I not allowed to have 2 Cursors?

Comment: if `c.moveToFirst` returns false that means there is nothing in your cursor

Comment: The problem is to get the string from cursor D

Comment: Probably you need to execute `d.moveToFirst()` as well... ?

Comment: @user2927356 : You're taking the wrong approach by using two `Cursors`. Use a conditional query with a single `Cursor`. Something along the lines of `SELECT TABLE1.some_column, TABLE2.other_colomn WHERE TABLE1.some_column = TABLE2.other_column`. The dataset returned to the `Cursor` will then contain 0 or more rows.